# Trying to read a text file...but not getting all the contents

Tags: string, matlab, text, file-io, textscan

I am trying to read the file with the following format which repeats itself (but I have cut out the data even for the first repetition because of it being too long):

```
1.00 'day' 2011-01-02
'Total Velocity Magnitude RC - Matrix' 'm/day'
    0.190189     0.279141     0.452853      0.61355     0.757833     0.884577 
    0.994502      1.08952      1.17203      1.24442      1.30872      1.36653 
     1.41897      1.46675      1.51035      1.55003      1.58595      1.61824
```

**Download the actual file** with the complete data [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44478670/single_phase_flow_scale1%20Total%20Velocity%20Magnitude%20RC.txt)

This is my code which I am using to read the data from the above file:

```
fid = fopen(file_name); % open the file

dotTXT_fileContents = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n'); % read it as string ('%s') into one big array, row by row
dotTXT_fileContents = dotTXT_fileContents{1};
fclose(fid); %# don't forget to close the file again

%# find rows containing 'Total Velocity Magnitude RC - Matrix' 'm/day'
data_starts = strmatch('''Total Velocity Magnitude RC - Matrix'' ''m/day''',...
    dotTXT_fileContents); % data_starts contains the line numbers wherever 'Total Velocity Magnitude RC - Matrix' 'm/day' is found

ndata = length(data_starts); % total no. of data values will be equal to the corresponding no. of '**  K' read from the .txt file

%# loop through the file and read the numeric data
for w = 1:ndata-1
    %# read lines containing numbers
    tmp_str = dotTXT_fileContents(data_starts(w)+1:data_starts(w+1)-3); % stores the content from file dotTXT_fileContents of the rows following the row containing 'Total Velocity Magnitude RC - Matrix' 'm/day' in form of string
    %# convert strings to numbers
    tmp_str = tmp_str{:}; % store the content of the string which contains data in form of a character
    %# assign output
    data_matrix_grid_wise(w,:) = str2num(tmp_str); % convert the part of the character containing data into number
end
```

To give you an idea of pattern of data in my text file, these are some results from the code:

```
data_starts =

           2
        1672
        3342
        5012
        6682
        8352
       10022

ndata =

     7
```

Therefore, my `data_matrix_grid_wise` should contain `1672-2-2-1(for a new line)=1667` rows. However, I am getting this as the result:

```
data_matrix_grid_wise =

  Columns 1 through 2

   0.190189000000000   0.279141000000000
   0.423029000000000   0.616590000000000
   0.406297000000000   0.604505000000000
   0.259073000000000   0.381895000000000
   0.231265000000000   0.338288000000000
   0.237899000000000   0.348274000000000

  Columns 3 through 4

   0.452853000000000   0.613550000000000
   0.981086000000000   1.289920000000000
   0.996090000000000   1.373680000000000
   0.625792000000000   0.859638000000000
   0.547906000000000   0.743446000000000
   0.562903000000000   0.759652000000000

  Columns 5 through 6

   0.757833000000000   0.884577000000000
   1.534560000000000   1.714330000000000
   1.733690000000000   2.074690000000000
   1.078000000000000   1.277930000000000
   0.921371000000000   1.080570000000000
   0.934820000000000   1.087410000000000
```

Where am I wrong? In my final result, I should get `data_matrix_grid_wise` composed of `10000` elements instead of `36` elements. Thanks.

**Update:** How can I include the number before 'day' i.e. 1,2,3 etc. on a line just before the data_starts(w)? I am using this within the loop but it doesn't seem to work:

```
days_str = dotTXT_fileContents(data_starts(w)-1);
    days_str = days_str{1};
    days(w,:) = sscanf(days_str(w-1,:), '%d %*s %*s', [1, inf]);
```

Comment: something wrong with you `dotTXT_fileContents()`? where is its code?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. `dotTXT_fileContents` is just a variable which is using `textscan()` to read a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in line  tmp_str = tmp_str{:};  Matlab have strange behaviour when handling chars. Short solution for you is replace last with the next two lines:

```
y = cell2mat( cellfun(@(z) sscanf(z,'%f'),tmp_str,'UniformOutput',false));
data_matrix_grid_wise(w,:) = y;
```

Comment: Singlet: How can I include the number before *'day'* i.e. 1,2,3 etc. on a line just before the data_starts(w)? I am using this within the loop but it doesn't seem to work: `days_str = dotTXT_fileContents(data_starts(w)-1);
    days_str = days_str{1}
    days(w,:) = sscanf(days_str(w-1,:), '%d %*s %*s', [1, inf]);`

Comment: If you want extract only integer number before 'day' word just use next code:  `days_str = dotTXT_fileContents(data_starts(w)-1);    
    days(w) = sscanf(days_str{1}, '%d');`   I haven't idea about  purpose (w-1,:) indexer in you code

Comment: Oh, that `(w-1,:)` was a typo :). Thanks, btw!!

Comment: Singlet: In some of the data files (like the one I have given link to) have days with decimal numbers. In that case I am just getting the number before the decimal and no decimals. Do you know how to include the decimal part as well...like for example I want the day to store `2.2` instead of just `2`. Thanks.

Comment: Just change %d specifier in sscanf to %f for reading float point values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with last 2 statements. When you do `tmp_str{:}` you convert cell array to comma-separated list of strings. If you assign this list to a single variable, only the first string is assigned. So the `tmp_str` will now have only the first row of data.

Here is what you can do instead of last 2 lines:

```
tmp_mat = cellfun(@str2num, tmp_str, 'uniformoutput',0);
data_matrix_grid_wise(w,:) = cell2mat(tmp_mat);
```

However, you will have a problem with concatenation (`cell2mat`) since not all of your rows have the same number of columns. It's depends on you how to solve it.